# JavaCompiler - set the compiled class output folder

Tags: java, eclipse, class, compiler-construction

I'm using Eclipse and therefore my class files are stored in "**bin**" in the project folder. How can I set the JavaCompiler to output compiled classes into this "**bin**" folder?

My code:

```
File fRun = new File("FileToCompile");
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null);
Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compUnits =  fileManager.getJavaFileObjects(fRun);
Boolean compRes = compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, null, null, null, compUnits).call();          

if(compRes == true){
    System.out.println("Compilation has succeeded");
    ClassLoader cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    Class<?> compiledClass = cl.loadClass("data.testcases.TestA");
    cRun = compiledClass;
}else{
    System.out.println("Compilation error");
    fileManager.close();
```

Comment: Need to pass your compiler options in compiler.getTask. The option is -d

Comment: Shouldn't this be the answer instead of a comment, @AmitBhargava?

Comment: Heh. Thought it wasn't detailed enough, so I let it be a comment. I'll add an answer too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Need to pass your compiler options in compiler.getTask. The option is -d

Comment: and where do I add compiler options?

Comment: This would be the fourth parameter. Now, I haven't tried this out but the following code fragment should help : final Iterable<String> options =
Arrays.asList( new String[] { "-d", <path>} ); where <path> is the absolute path for your bin directory